# AJAX POST problems with CKFinder

Tags: php, ajax, post, ckfinder

We're using CKFinder for one of our sites, which has been working fine for us until we moved to a new dedicated server (which is similar but not exactly the same as the old server). Now we cant upload, the AJAX request simply never finishes.

From monitoring it in Firebug it attempts to POST to here:
http://www.site.com/temp/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=FileUpload&type=Files&currentFolder=%2F&hash=4f9cdbbb1e295966&langCode=en&=

but never gets a response.

This is the same CKFinder install on both WIMP servers, one works fine one doesnt. any idea where we should be looking to fix this problem? php.ini maybe?

any help would be great as we havent a clue at this stage. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My first inclination would be to check server permissions..or more specifically folder/file permissions in that directory.  Apache must have write privileges to that folder in order for any upload mechanism to work successfully.

Of course, I'm not referring to the folder in which connector.php resides but rather the folder that CKFinder has setup as its default upload location.  For example, if you're server is linux-based you could try this:

```
$ chown -R ftp_user:apache /path/to/doc_root/path/to/ckfinder_media
$ chmod -R 775 /path/to/doc_root/path/to/ckfinder_media
```

If you're running on Red Hat or CentOS it would probably be something like /var/www/vhosts/site.com/public_html (for the document root).  That's if you've setup virtual hosts.  If not, you would find it in a path like /var/www/public_html.